# How can i add a history pushstate without trigger vue.js router change?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

Commonly,history.pushState() will trigger component rendering when using vue router,and that component will not get rendered but i don't want add a link for this.

As I want push a state for the modal showing without using vue router,hack like `history.back()` will not work.

More info is i want add history for a modal,and when history go back close that modal.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to add a history entry without actually going to the target destination? Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: I've updated.history pushstate just conflicts with vue router.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to link a modal dialogs state to the history back event so that it's closed if the user tries to go back one step in the browser history? Because it would be easier to grab the inputs that trigger a history back event in that case and make them trigger the modal close function instead. This can be done either by setting up event listeners for various keyboard/mouse inputs, or by temporarily reassigning the history.back() function to your own custom function that closes the modal window, then reassigning the original function back to it.

Comment: Yeah,that's the point,but if i change the back function ,will other router works?Hit the back when modal is showing,it will go to another tab curently.

Comment: I'll try to cloase the tab using vue router's hook like `beforeRouteEnter`

Comment: But add a history state for the modal is still better,then hitting back will not go to another tab,but simply close the modal,just like native app.

Comment: If it's specifically just for the back button you want to listen for there are ways to get just the back button. document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
function onBackKeyDown() {
// Handle the back button
}

Comment: No,man,there is no such event,i'll try popstate event

Comment: Turns out that my above solution is specific to Cordova apps. If possible I'd recommend you turn your website into a Cordova app, makes it installable on several platforms and adds a bunch of functionalities without compromising any of your browser based functions. It's essentially just a project that takes your website and makes it installable and displayed through native web viewers. That way you can make your app feel waaaaay more native, if that's what you're going for. You can e.g. add legit Android buttons to your website if you want.

Comment: Thanks,man.I'll think about it.